# tcl: How to determine shell for module command

Tags: tcl

I am programming in tcl (for use with the modules command). I need to find out what shell is being used by the user. Since I've never programmed in tcl before, I don't know what is wrong with my simple code. Can someone please advise?

```
set shell [module-info shell]
if { $shell=="bash" } {
    puts "running bash"
}
```

The error I'm getting (sorry I didn't include it originally) is:

```
intel64(32):ERROR:102: Tcl command execution failed: if { $shell == "bash" } {
    puts "running bash
}
```

Note that intel64 is the file where this code is found and line 34 is the last line.

Comment: Can you give us the output of the `$shell` variable (`puts $shell`) resp. the `module-info shell` output (`puts [module-info shell]`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single quotes have no special meaning for Tcl.  In Tcl, double quotes are analogous to shell double quotes, and braces (`{}`) are analogous to shell single quotes. You would want to write

```
if { $shell == "bash" } ...
```

See the entire syntax of Tcl documented here: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/Tcl.htm

That doesn't explain the error message though. Tcl itself does not have a `system` command. I can't say how this "modules command" extends Tcl. Try

```
puts "running bash"
```

or if you really really want to use `echo`, then

```
exec echo running bash
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I have updated my script and the original question to reflect the single vs. double quotes. Unfortunately, it didn't help.

Comment: Yep, I was missing a close-quote. Now everything works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

2 comments:

1. use **puts** to display the value of **$shell**, so you can
   see exactly what's going on.
2. your **else** needs to be on
   the same line as the right curly bracket before it.
3. You say that the value of $shell is 'bash'. If so then you will need to change your **if** statement and put double quotes around it e.g. **"'bash'"**.

Comment: Thanks for the update, @Brian. In my other comment, I didn't mean that the value of $shell included the single quotes. Sorry for the confusion. Updated my original question to make it simpler.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you *should not* use puts when using the modules software.

modules is just a tcl program that modifies *somehow* your shell environment in a shell-independent manner. This is done via a simple trick, check your environment:

```
set | grep -A 10 module
...
module () 
{ 
    eval `/modules-3.2.9/Modules/$MODULE_VERSION/bin/modulecmd bash $*`
}
```

So the trick is creating a proper string that is then evaluated by the current shell. That string comes from stdout so what should have happened after it *worked* is that your shell should have complaint about trying to evaluate "running bash"

I'm puzzled as to why it's supposed to have worked after you added the missing quote.

Answer (score 0):

```
set shell $::env(SHELL)
switch -glob $shell {
  "/bin/tcsh" -
  "/bin/csh" {
  setenv foamDotFile $env(FOAM_INST_DIR)/OpenFOAM-2.3.0/etc/cshrc
  }
  "/bin/ksh" -
  "/bin/bash" {
  setenv foamDotFile $env(FOAM_INST_DIR)/OpenFOAM-2.3.0/etc/bashrc
  }
}
```